# Selecting columns of first matrix based on non-zero column of second matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given two matrices **A** and **B** of shape **[m,n]** and **[n,n]** respectively.
I want a third matrix **C** of shape **[m,n]** such that:

1. `C[:,i] = A[:,i] if B[:,i] != 0` (i.e. there is some non-zero entry in
   ith column of matrix B)
2. `C[:,i] = 0` otherwise

Notation: C[:,i] represents the ith column of matrix C and 0 represents 0 vector.

Is there any sequence of matrix operations in linear algebra such as multiplication, addition, an elementwise addition/multiplication, etc. that can be applied on A and B to achieve the above goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$C=A\times diag(\vec v)$$
where $\vec v$ is an $n$ dimensional vector and $i^{th}$ entry of $\vec v$ is absolute value of the signum of $i^{th}$ diagonal entry of $B^TB$. In short, $i^{th}$ entry of $\vec v$ is the indicator function of $i^{th}$ column of $B$.

$diag(\vec x)$ is defined to be a diagonal matrix with $\vec x$ in its diagonal entries, i.e.
$$diag(\vec x) = \sum_{i=1}^ne_i^\top\vec x e_ie_i^\top$$

Comment: I guess the correct solution is  `A#u*vT`, where # is the elementwise matrix product and * is the usual matrix product. Is that correct, @Martund?

Comment: @abhi, I have edited my answer. How do you define elementwise product for two matrices not of the same order?

Comment: yeah, I missed that part.